# Deployment of drop wizard application using java -jar command

Tags: java, dropwizard

I build my application and I got the jar file.
I copies the jar file to my server. I tried to deploy the jar file using the following command in the terminal.

> java -jar myapp.jar server xxx.yml

The appilcation starts fine. The terminal will be waiting since the server is running. When I close the terminal, application also stops. But I need to make it running even after the terminal closing. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

`nohup java -jar myapp.jar server xxx.yml &`

Answer (score 2):

Using `nohup` as others have mentioned will work fine for a one time application. If you want to turn it into a real service that starts up automatically when the computer starts up and restarts automatically on error, you should probably use a service monitor of some kind. There are a lot of options and some depend on your distribution.

In Ubuntu 14.04 with [upstart](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/) you can write the following to `/etc/init/my-dropwizard.conf`:

```
author "my name"
description "my dropwizard service"

respawn
respawn limit 5 10

chdir /home/me
exec java -server -jar myapp.jar server xxx.yml
```

And then run this to start it for the first time:

```
initctl start my-dropwizard
```

If you're using Ubuntu 16.06 with [systemd](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/) you can write the following to `/etc/systemd/system/my-service.service`:

```
[Unit]
Description=my dropwizard service
After=local-fs.target network.target

[Service]
User=root
WorkingDirectory=/home/me
ExecStart=java -server -jar myapp.jar server xxx.yml
Restart=always

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

And then run this to start it for the first time:

```
systemctl start my-service
```

There are also generic service monitors like [God](http://godrb.com/), [Supervisor](http://supervisord.org/) and others.

Answer (score 0):

If the OS is Linux, use nohup to run your java cmd.

Comment: Showing the following error nohup: ignoring input and redirecting stderr to stdout. I tried [link](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/45913/is-there-a-way-to-redirect-nohup-output-to-a-log-file-other-than-nohup-out) but still not working